# How did the cab driver know Steve & Joe?

Tags: blues-clues

In *[Blue's Big City Adventure](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt15038118/)*, near the climax of the film, Josh, Steve, Joe, Blue and the other character's from Storybook Land all pile into a taxi cab. The taxi cab driver is played by [Alex Winter](https://www.imdb.com/name/nm0935664/).

The cab driver is familiar with both the sayings from Blue's Clues, and the Blue's Clues theme song. Despite Steve saying "It's nice to meet you", the cab driver says he feels like he already knows them. Steve and Joe do not disagree, and also seem familiar with the cab driver, even if they are not certain why.

What was this in reference to? Why did he feel he already knew Steve and Joe? It's not mentioned again in the movie, and my searching so far reveals no previous association between Alex Winter and Blue's Clues (except for a *[Robot Chicken](https://robotchicken.fandom.com/wiki/Blue%27s_Bad_News)* parody which I highly doubt is the intended reference).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The film's Director Matt Stawski addressed this in an interview with ComingSoon. As far as he's aware, Winter had no special connection to the makers and his appearance in the film was simply a professional cameo, along with several others that the studio paid for. The director was personally aware of Winter from his work on *Bill & Ted* and *The Lost Boys*, and more recently as a filmmaker, but he doesn't seem to have had any prior dealings with him, nor Winter with Blue's Clues.

> **Q. Speaking about a more adult-oriented cameo, I was curious about Alex Winter. That whole scene where him and Steve are saying the same stuff. Was that a reference to the Robot Chicken sketch he did where he voiced Steve, or what was that about?**
>
> ***That just happens to be a coincidence, actually. The fact that he voiced Steve in that Robot Chicken episode, I learned about that episode after we shot the movie.** I didn’t even know about it beforehand. **That just happens to be a coincidence, but him being in there was huge for me because obviously, I’m a die-hard Bill & Ted and a huge Lost Boys fan.** Alex, now, is a big documentary filmmaker, so he’s just an incredible filmmaker artist through and through. It was so fun to have that character as well as putting him in that scene that has that Wayne’s World homage to it. It was this full circle moment with old characters [and] new characters rocking out to the Blue’s Clues song in a Wayne’s World style. It was just pure fun, you know?*
>
> <sub><sup>[Interview: Blue’s Big City Adventure Director Matt Stawski on Nostalgia & His Pop-Punk Roots](https://www.comingsoon.net/movies/features/1249474-blues-big-city-adventure-interview-matt-stawski)</sup></sub>

Comment: Wow, I surprised that he didn't know about the Robot Chicken connection! That's a great find though, thanks. Just a random fun moment with no extra connection

Comment: @Tronman - A lot of celebrity cameos are just paid-for appearances. You get money for basically showing up for a day of work. You don't even need to learn lines. They just hold up an idiot-board and you say what's in front of you.

Answer (score -1):

Yes actually. That's the literal only connection and according to an interview with the director, the interviewer brought up the exact same question to the director and the director stated that he didn't know that and that it was so cool. Perhaps Alex winters snuck in the line and luckily got the role and timed it correctly.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: "an interview with the director"? Which interview, where?